# Why doesn't this integral equal 0?

Tags: calculus

The integral is of $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x^3}$. If you're looking at the graph, the area should obviously cancel out to $0$. However, if you do it mathematically you get a positive number. Why isn't the area $0$? Thanks

Comment: How are you getting a positive number?

Comment: This function is not integrable on $(-1,1)$. Maybe you are looking for the Cauchy principal value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a non-integrable singularity at $x=0$.  If you use the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral, you will get zero:

$$\begin{align}PV \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{x^3}& = \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \left [\int_{-1}^{-y} \frac{dx}{x^3} + \int_{y}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^3} \right ]\\ &= \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \left [ -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2 y^2} - \frac{1}{2 y^2} +\frac{1}{2} \right ]\\ &= 0 \end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

It’s an improper integral:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x^3}&=\lim_{a\to 0^-}\int_{-1}^a\frac{dx}{x^3}+\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_a^1\frac{dx}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{a\to 0^-}\left[\frac{-1}{2x^2}\right]_{-1}^a+\lim_{a\to 0^+}\left[\frac{-1}{2x^2}\right]_a^1\;,
\end{align*}$$

which is easily seen not to exist.

Comment: @Baby Dragon: Thanks!

Comment: You very welcome.

Comment: What do you think about the Ron's answer which showed that the area is 0? I really can't say for myself, Cauchy is way beyond me, I am only a student in highschool calculus.

Comment: @Ovi: The [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) is a way of assigning a value to an improper integral that is undefined when interpreted in the usual fashion. This particular integral does have a Cauchy principal value of $0$, meaning **very** roughly that even though the areas on both sides of $x=0$ are infinite, they’re infinite ‘in the same way’, but in the usual sense of a Riemann integral it’s undefined.

Answer (score 3):

The integral 
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^\alpha}$$
is divergent if $\alpha\geq1$, hence your given integral is also divergent since $0\in(-1,1)$.